# ¿como subir un archivo a partir de una url, a un directorio por ftp? en php

Tags: php, codeigniter, ftp

Estoy tratando de guardar un archivo por ftp, si cargo el archivo de manera local lo sube sin problema, pero yo necesito cargarlo a partir de una url, entre las formas que probé no me ha funcionado, necesito ayuda en esto por favor, Gracias.

```
        $this->load->library('ftp');

        $config['hostname'] = 'ftp.example.com';
        $config['username'] = 'your-username';
        $config['password'] = 'your-password';
        $config['port'] = 21;
        $config['passive'] = FALSE;
        $config['debug'] = TRUE;

        $this->ftp->connect($config);

        //$localPath = "C:\prueba\prueba.pdf"; //--Directorio del archivo Local, Envia normal
        $localPath = "https://caseriadehuellar.com/documentos/Noticias/documento%20prueba.pdf";//--No puedo subir este
        $serverPath = "/public_html/myfile.pdf";

        $this->ftp->upload($localPath, $serverPath, 'binary', 0775);

        $this->ftp->close();
```

Si lo cargo directamente la url, me bota este error "Unable to locate the source file. Please check your path.".

Comment: QUé significa "No ha funcionado"? Qué error sale? QUé ves en los logs de PHP? Edita tu pregunta y especifica el error (los errores)

Comment: al ser una url, me sale que no se puede localizar el archivo origen.

Comment: La traza de error se pone EN la pregunta. Así no nos cuentas qué dice sino que vemos qué dice :). Lo otro: esto lo estás haciendo en COdeIgniter, cierto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segun [la documentación](https://codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/ftp.html) [oficial](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/ftp.html), tienes que entregar una ruta local en ese primer parámetro.

> Uploads a file to your server. You must supply the local path and the remote path, and you can optionally set the mode and permissions.
>
> Example:
> $this->ftp->upload('/local/path/to/myfile.html', '/public_html/myfile.html', 'ascii', 0775);

Así pues, una ruta remota no se puede resolver.
Necesitas entonces, descargar el archivo a una ubicación temporal y ahí sí, cargarlo en tu FTP de destino.